# Rest API for lucene search

Tags: java, api, web-services, lucene, intellij-14

I had successfully created a program for Lucene indexing and searching. Now, I need to implement rest API for my Lucene I stuck with some error.

Can anyone please insist me that how to implement rest API to retrieve my documents while using Lucene search?

I got "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error" while including Lucene code.
I hereby attached my code contains REST-API and Lucene search.

```java
@Path("/lucene")
public class hello {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello(@QueryParam("startdate") Date startdate,
                        @QueryParam("enddate") Date enddate,
                        @QueryParam("services") String services,
                        @QueryParam("type") String type) throws IOException {
        String hello = hellosearch(startdate, enddate, services, type);
        return hello;
    }


    private String hellosearch(Date startdate, Date enddate, String services, String type) throws IOException {

        final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final String index = "purple";

        IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(index)));
        final IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        final Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();

        Date startDate = startdate;
        Date endDate = enddate;
        String service = services;
        String types = type;

        TopDocs results = searchDetails(searcher,startDate, endDate, service, types);

        ScoreDoc[] hits = results.scoreDocs;
        int numTotalHits = Math.toIntExact(results.totalHits.value);
        int end = numTotalHits;
        String resource = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
            Document doc = searcher.doc(hits[i].doc);
            System.out.println("    service  :" + doc.get("services"));
            System.out.println("    type     :" + doc.get("type"));
            System.out.println("    message  :" + doc.get("message"));
            resource = resource + "services   : " + doc.get("services") + "\ntype    : " + doc.get("type") + "\nmessage  : " + doc.get("message") + "\n";

        }
        return resource;
    }


    private TopDocs searchDetails(IndexSearcher searcher,Date startdate, Date enddate, String service, String types) throws IOException {
        String field = "";
        long millis = 0;

        Date startDate = startdate;

        Date endDate = enddate;

        long startmillis = startDate.getTime();
        long endmillis = endDate.getTime();
        String upperdate = DateTools.dateToString(new Date(startmillis), DateTools.Resolution.SECOND);
        String lowerdate = DateTools.dateToString(new Date(endmillis), DateTools.Resolution.SECOND);

        TermRangeQuery query = new TermRangeQuery("date", new BytesRef(upperdate), new BytesRef(lowerdate), true, true);

        String services = service;
        Term term1 = new Term("services", services);
        Query query1 = new WildcardQuery(term1);


        String type = types;
        Term term2 = new Term("type", type);
        Query query2 = new FuzzyQuery(term2);

        Query query3 = new MatchAllDocsQuery();

        BooleanQuery booleanquery = new BooleanQuery.Builder().add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
                .add(query1, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
                .add(query2, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST)
                .add(query3, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST).build();

        TopDocs results = searcher.search(booleanquery, 200);
        return results;
    }
}
```

I had indexed a csv file and It contained date, services and type. I need to get `startdate` and `enddate` from the user along with services and type so that I need to retrieve indexed documents matching the given services and type within the particular dates.

Comment: I would suggest to use Apache Solr which is completely based upon Apache Lucene, it provides Rest endpoints for searching. Also you can use Elastic Search which also provides Rest End Points.

Comment: When you receive a http 500 error in the rest client - you also should be able to see corresponding error log in the server's log (eclipse/intellij - what you're using for running the "backend"). Check there for more detailed information what is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem, it is more about passing the dates as parameter in Rest End Point. You can do it in the following manner.

```
public String hello(@RequestParam("startdate") @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yyyy") Date date,
                        ... other parameters ) throws IOException {
        .... other code
    }
```

or you can try to write like this.

```
public String hello(@RequestParam("startdate")  @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE) LocalDate localDate,
                        ... other parameters ) throws IOException {
        .... other code
    }
```

Apart from this, I would suggest to use Either Apache Solr or Elastic Search where you will get Rest end points for searching.